# How do you run a flask api and a discord bot at the same time on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, discord, discord.py

Ive created an api using discordoauth to log users in, from there i want to take their userid and check if they are under a specific role in my server. To do this i need to have a web api (using flask) and run a discord bot at the same time.

The problem lies on herokus end. When i run the program locally it workes fine. When i push to heroku, the flask app starts but the discord bot doesnt start.

I have tried to multithread the program and put the flask app on another thread. This too works only locally and not on the heroku server. There are no errors on the heroku server so im not sure whats going wrong. Im assuming it has something to do with the threading.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    partial_run = partial(app.run,debug=False,threaded=True,use_reloader=False)

    t = Thread(target=partial_run)
    t.start()
    client.run(token)
```

The expected result is to have both programs running at once, instead on heroku only the flask app starts.

Locally, it works fine.